# Valid json returning error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

When making this call:

```
function TopDonorCheck() {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://coebot.tv/api/v1/vars/get/top-donor/supermcgamer",
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (TopDonorData) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(TopDonorData));
        console.log(TopDonorData);
    }
});
}
```

The response is:

```
{"value":"TheRealLemon","description":"","lastModified":1431276238,"status":"ok"}
```

I can't figure out what is wrong. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have a closing brace at the end of your function?

Comment: Is the error only being thrown when you make the call or even without making the call, like on page load?

Comment: It helps when your code formatting is standard and easy to read; You might want to just run your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 0):

You have `dataType: 'jsonp'` but your data isn't [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), it's plain JSON.  Change your ajax call to `dataType: 'json'`.  See the documentation of `dataType` at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/